# curl slow connect_time

Tags: php, curl

Consider this code in a php file on my VPS server:

```
<?php $url = 'http://www.google.com';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3)     Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$ci = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($ci); ?>
```

returns this

```
array(22) { 
["url"]=> string(21) "http://www.google.com" 
["content_type"]=> string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
["http_code"]=> int(200) 
["header_size"]=> int(2055) 
["request_size"]=> int(147) 
["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
["total_time"]=> float(50.095466) 
["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.001114) 
["connect_time"]=> float(50.019724) 
["pretransfer_time"]=> float(50.019825) 
["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
["size_download"]=> float(23156) 
["speed_download"]=> float(462) 
["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
["upload_content_length"]=> float(0) 
["starttransfer_time"]=> float(50.070702) 
["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } 
["redirect_url"]=> string(0) 
"" }
```

After testing at several times of day, the "connect_time" is consistently at the 50 seconds mark. I believe it should be 10X faster if not at the 1 second mark and below.

I'm not knowledgeable with server config but I was told that my server's CPU or RAM could be at fault. I used the top command line to display the following which seems fine to me:

> Tasks:  80 total,   1 running,  79 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
>
> Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,
>   0.0%st
>
> Mem:   2097152k total,  1273128k used,   824024k free,        0k
>   buffers
>
> Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k
>   cached

I am wondering what could be the source of this issue ?

EDIT: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

ping www.google.com result. It seemed like it could go on foreover so I stopped the command after the 195th line

> PING www.l.google.com (74.125.224.178) 56(84) bytes of data.
>
> 64 bytes from lax02s01-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.224.178): icmp_seq=1
>   ttl=56 time=12.0 ms
>
> 64 bytes from lax02s01-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.224.178): icmp_seq=2
>   ttl=56 time=12.1 ms
>
> 64 bytes from lax02s01-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.224.178): icmp_seq=3
>   ttl=56 time=11.9 ms
>
> ...
>
> 64 bytes from lax02s01-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.224.178): icmp_seq=194
>   ttl=56 time=11.9 ms
>
> 64 bytes from lax02s01-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.224.178): icmp_seq=195
>   ttl=56 time=11.9 ms
>
> --- www.l.google.com ping statistics --- 195 packets transmitted, 194 received, 0% packet loss, time 194711ms

traceroute wwww.google.com result

> traceroute to www.google.com (74.125.224.180), 30 hops max, 60 byte
>   packets
>
> 1  ip-*-*-*-*.ip.secureserver.net (*.*.*.*)  0.585 ms 
>   0.642 ms  0.778 ms
>
> 2  be10.trmd0215-01.ars.mgmt.phx3.gdg (208.109.112.126)  0.599 ms 
>   0.777 ms  0.893 ms
>
> 3  ip-97-74-253-122.ip.secureserver.net (97.74.253.122)  11.840 ms 
>   12.119 ms  12.275 ms
>
> 4  ip-97-74-253-122.ip.secureserver.net (97.74.253.122)  12.389 ms 
>   12.482 ms  12.600 ms
>
> 5  PR01.LAX03.google.com (206.223.123.21)  11.739 ms  11.709 ms 
>   11.707 ms
>
> 6  209.85.248.185 (209.85.248.185)  11.986 ms  11.797 ms  11.781 ms
>
> 7  72.14.236.11 (72.14.236.11)  12.606 ms  12.363 ms  12.328 ms
>
> 8  lax02s01-in-f20.1e100.net (74.125.224.180)  11.774 ms  11.864 ms 
>   11.842 ms

Comment: What type of network connection do you have, what do resources on the VPS host look like? Running the above works within 1-3 seconds for me on several platforms. It is something local to your setup. Can you ping/traceroute to google and update your question? This should probably be in serverfault.

Comment: thank you sixeightzero, I added that information to my question

Comment: changed my resolver configuration (resolv.config) to Google's nameserver ip. Didn't help

Comment: > curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

this does the trick

Firstly I narrowed down the problem to cURL jobs fetching the url google.com. Other URLs were fine, cURL performed well, even when using G's ip address as url.

It seems that google has IPv6 enabled but the traffic doesn't route correctly/at all and perhaps cURL times out.

Many thanks to everyone that helped.

Comment: nice catch! This is a great question and resolution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

The above will prevent cURL from trying IPv6 first.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP comments, this does the trick. It would seem that google.com has IPV6 enabled but the traffic is routed incorrectly. cURL seemed to timed out (which would explain the constant connect_time of 50ish seconds) and eventually fall back on IPV4 to connect. Thanks to all who helped

Comment: I love you StackOverflow. This helped me with more than just Google.com, but it was definitely screwing with my API calls. I noticed my remote server did IPv4 by default which is why it was significantly faster than my localhost.

Comment: We just switched servers and the new server was giving timeout errors. I managed to find the source of problem as curl connect time. I was trying to solve slow connect time issue for a full day. You just saved me from spending more hours into this hideous problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the same configuration you gave and got the following:

```
array
  'url' => string 'http://www.google.com' (length=21)
  'content_type' => string 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
  'http_code' => int 200
  'header_size' => int 2079
  'request_size' => int 151
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 0.281
  'namelookup_time' => float 0
  'connect_time' => float 0
  'pretransfer_time' => float 0
  'size_upload' => float 0
  'size_download' => float 23168
  'speed_download' => float 82448
  'speed_upload' => float 0
  'download_content_length' => float -1
  'upload_content_length' => float 0
  'starttransfer_time' => float 0.187
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'certinfo' => 
  array
    empty
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
```

My guess is that your server connection itself might be having bandwidth issues and/or being taxed somehow by another process.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes this is the kind of time values I believe are normal for this cURL job.  Do you see anything wrong with the result of the top command that I posted above ?