# cURL on DreamHost Slow taking ~20 seconds

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, dreamhost

Curling the Facebook API from DreamHost is super slow. Sometimes it comes back in 1-2 seconds, other times 20 seconds. It has been really messing up my site.

```
function curlUrl($url, $post = null) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101');

    if ($post):
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    endif;

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `curl_getinfo` after the `curl_exec` showed that the connect_time was very slow.

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
```

Found this article [curl slow connect_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143180/curl-slow-connect-time)

Adding this line sped things up a ton!

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```